# What language does Berta speak?

Tags: dialogue, gilmore-girls

In [*Gilmore Girls: A Year In The Life*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5435008/), what language does Emily's new maid Berta speak?

At first I thought it was Spanish, but it seems to clearly be something else.

Comment: Seems to have been a completely made up language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Berta's native tongue definitely has Spanish and Portuguese influences, but the creators pretty much made up a fake language for Berta and her family to speak. The concept seems to have been that even though she didn't completely understand what they were saying, Emily was able to communicate and bond with Berta in a way that she hadn't been able to with previous maids.